# How to get access to a file from one child module into another child module in maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, rpm-maven-plugin

This is my maven project Structure:

```
Parent Module
|
|---Child Module A
       |
       |--target/xyz.jar (generated during mvn clean install)
|---Child Module B
       |
       |--target/abc.jar (generated during mvn clean install)
       |--rpm-maven-plugin (in pom.xml file)
```

Reactor Build Order:
 1. Parent 
 2. Child A 
 3. Child B

I want to access xyz.jar in mappings sources so that the rpm contains/bundles both abc.jar and xyz.jar inside a single rpm. I tried doing

> ./Child A/target/xyz.jar

and

> Child A/target/xyz.jar

but it says source location does not exists. I am not sure how maven can traverse from one child module to another child module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do not access other artifacts through relative paths, but you use the Maven coordinates. After `clean install`, the respective artifact is in your local repository, so you can get it through its GAV. If you need to copy it, look at the `dependency:copy` goal.